# MATLAB scaled repmat

Tags: performance, matlab

Is there an easy way to have a scaled repmat in matlab?

The idea is, given matrices `A` and `B`

```
result = [A*B(1, 1) A*B(1, 2) A*B(1, 3) ... 

          A*B(1, n); A*B(2, 1)...];
```

Right now I accomplish this by using permute and reshape, but the permutation operation is 90% of my script time.

Comment: You should share your current code. `permute` and `reshape` are quite fast. And please share a example data with your desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`kron`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html):

```
result = kron(B, A);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably performing the elementwise multiplications that results in a huge array and then permuting. Now, `permute` on a big array would incur heavy data transfers, which won't be efficient. So, I am guessing you are doing something along these lines :

```
reshape(permute(bsxfun(@times,A,permute(B,[3,4,1,2])),[1,3,2,4]),N,[]) 
           ^ (kills performance)
```

The alternative is to perform `permute` on `A` and `B` before performing elementwise multiplications between the input arrays, such that finally we would just need a `reshape`. Permuting on comparatively `A` and `B` should be much more efficient.

So, one efficient solution would be -

```
n = size(A,1)*size(B,1);
out = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1,3,2]),permute(B,[3,1,4,2])),n,[]);
```

**Runtime test**

Let's time the two approaches to verify our performance improvements and also include `kron` based method as suggested in @Shai's post, which seems like a clean solution -

```
% Max sized input arrays that my system could handle
A = randi(9,70,70);
B = randi(9,70,70);

disp('-------------- With permute on A and B and finally reshaping')
tic
n = size(A,1)*size(B,1);
out0 = reshape(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1,3,2]),permute(B,[3,1,4,2])),n,[]);
toc, clear out0 n

disp('-------------- With permute on elementwise result')
tic
n = size(A,1)*size(B,1);
out1 = reshape(permute(bsxfun(@times,A,permute(B,[3,4,1,2])),[1,3,2,4]),n,[]);
toc, clear out1 n

disp('-------------- With kron from @Shai post')
tic,
result1 = kron(B, A);
toc
```

Timings -

```
-------------- With permute on A and B and finally reshaping
Elapsed time is 0.161598 seconds.
-------------- With permute on elementwise result
Elapsed time is 0.413746 seconds.
-------------- With kron from @Shai post
Elapsed time is 0.612825 seconds.
```

Comment: Your answer was really helpful. My current bottleneck is a sum function after the kron/bsxfun operations. Basically A and B are now 3-Dimensional. let's say k = 5.
A = randi(9,70,70, 5);
B = randi(9,70,70, 5);

out0 = reshape(sum(bsxfun(@times,permute(A,[1,4,2, 5,3]),permute(B,[4,1,5,2,3])), 5),n, n2,[]);

This is much slower than using my original permutations, is there a built in function to do this? I want to use CUDA but would rather not implement my own kernel.

Comment: @Felipe With those new requirements it would make more sense to post a new question. You could move these codes onto the new question.